# MySQL query for grouping data

Tags: mysql

can anyone please guide me with writing MySQL query for following scenario.

The data in table is like this,

```
Table Name: user

user_id     country     city            age
----------------------------------------------
1           India       Mumbai          22
2           India       Mumbai          22
3           India       Delhi           22
4           India       Delhi           23
5           India       Chennai         23
6           China       Beijing         20
7           China       Beijing         20
8           China       Shanghai        20
9           USA         New York        30
10          USA         New York        30
11          USA         New York        30
12          USA         Los Angeles     31
13          USA         Los Angeles     31
14          USA         Los Angeles     40
```

I want result to be like this which is basically sum of all users in particular country's city having same age.

```
country     city            age     age_count
----------------------------------------------
India       Mumbai          22          2
India       Delhi           22          1
India       Delhi           23          1
India       Chennai         23          1
China       Beijing         20          2
China       Shanghai        20          1
USA         New York        30          3
USA         Los Angeles     31          2
USA         Los Angeles     40          1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :;

```
SELECT country,
       city,
       age,
       count(user_id) AS age_count
FROM user
GROUP BY country,
         city,
         round(age)
```

Comment: One more thing what if age has some discrepancy e.g. some columns it has 22 other have 22.0. Any way to solve this?

Comment: You can typecast the age field, do you want me to modify?

Comment: Yes that would be of great help. Also I want to order rows by age_count but country, city display should remain as it is.

Comment: Have updated my query, but it will slow down your execution since if there is an index in city, it wont be considered

Comment: I tried this before your update,

I tried this before your update,

    Select 
    country, 
    city, 
    Cast(age as UNSIGNED) as age, 
    count(user_id) as age_count
    from user 
    
    group by country, city, age


But didn't worked. Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: Please check my edited answer, I am not casting it, I am rounding it off, which will be applicable in this scenario

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20250/discussion-between-whoru-and-sashi-kant)

Comment: I cannot, here it is blocked, but write down, what problems are you still facing

Comment: on few occasions it still shows 34.0 etc
My previous DBA had made age field as text.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20250/discussion-between-whoru-and-sashi-kant

Answer (score 3):

```
select country, city, age, count(*) age_count
from user 
group by country, city, age
```

Comment: Someone else is playing with ratings. Your query is just little slower than Sashi Kant's query.

Fetching 10000 rows,
Your query: 603.99 secs
Sashi Kant query: 586.27 secs